# Understand load average on multicore system

Tags: load-average

For only one microprocessor unit, the load average output by `top` could be understood that if it's above 1.0 then there are jobs waiting. But if we have n number of cores on a multicore system with `l*n` logical cores (on my Intel CPU n=6 and `l*n` = 12 so the output from `nproc` is 12), should we divide the load average by the output from `nproc` to see if that number is above 1 to understand if there are (on average) jobs waiting, or is it better to use `htop` to understand if a parallel multicore system is getting too much average load?

I think that my method was wrong but the conclusion was right when I saw that an average load was above 10 top, I checked with `ps` which process was expensive and found an overflow from a running program, but if that machine actually has output from `nproc` > 10 then it would not really have been cause for investigation if I had known that. Do you agree?

Comment: This might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303699/how-is-the-load-average-interpreted-in-top-output-is-it-the-same-for-all-di

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, you divide the load average across the cores. To understand load averages better I highly recommend this article by Brendan Gregg http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-08-08/linux-load-averages.html

Comment: Well If I'm reading it correctly just dividing across would not work I guess given if the system is under heavy load that does mean heavy CPU load it can be load IO  load too (like thread / process waiting on slow IO etc)