# During what kinds of operations is a process considered for the 'load average'?

Tags: linux, scheduling, load-average

In general, I'm trying to understand the numbers displayed by `uptime` (and numerous oder commands):

```
$ uptime
 13:40:52 up 18 days,  2:10,  8 users,  load average: 0.20, 0.30, 0.64
```

Here, my system's load average for the previous one-minute-interval was **0.2**. On a very high level, this number is telling me that, on average during the sampling period, **0.2** processes were considered as producing *load* for the system [2].

I understand that a process can be in many different states. But I only have a firm understanding for 3 main states:

1. The process is doing work on a CPU.
2. The process *could* be doing work right away but there are no free CPUs.
3. The process is waiting for something to happen on or outside the system.

I think the last state is the one to look at more closely because I'm quite certain that processes in the first two states are always counted for the system's *load*. I can imagine a few things that a system might do to get into the last state:

1. Calling `sleep()`.
2. Calling `read()` on an open file which is not in the cache.
3. Calling `read()` on a pipe into which no-one is writing anything.
4. Calling `accept()` on a network socket.
5. Calling `send()` on a network socket with a full buffer.
6. Trying to access private memory that has been swapped to disk.
7. Trying to access a memory mapped file that is not in the cache and has to be loaded from disk or a network file system.
8. Being unfortunate enough to jump to a piece of code that has not yet been loaded into memory.

I read [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9477/18016) and a few other resources on the internet and I've seen the terms *uninterruptable state* and *uninterruptable sleep* a few times and that processes in such a state are also counted. So I'm assuming that this would include *some* of the states above, but which ones? Definitely not all of them.

So my main question is, when *exactly* is a process counted towards the system's *load*?

#### Footnotes

[1]: E.g. out of **1000** samples, **200** times a single process [2] was counted while the other **800** times none were counted. Or **200** processes were counted once while none were counted the other **999** times. I get that.

[2]: I'm using *process* and *thread* interchangeably here because, to my understanding, from the viewpoint of the scheduler, they don't look all that different. For the interpretation of my question, please assume that I'm talking about a system where every process has exactly one thread. If there are interesting differences when looking at processes with multiple threads, please note them though!

Comment: The definitive answer to this, especially since you tagged your question [tag:linux], is [Brendan Gregg’s blog post on the topic](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-08-08/linux-load-averages.html).

Comment: @AlexP Either your statement is incorrect, or "some external event" should be clarified. A process waiting on disk or network IO, will very much contribute to load average.

Comment: @AlexP, Stephen's link seems to contradict you, at least as far as Linux is concerned. It wouldn't be bad if someone would write a brief summary of that article as an answer.

Comment: @AlexP "load average is simply the average length of the run queue" -- Where do you think processes waiting on I/O live? The run queue. In addition to the linked article, here's the current source which makes it pretty clear: https://goo.gl/zjw6T8

Comment: @ilkkachu: My age is showing, isn't it? I have deleted my previous misleading comments.

Comment: @Patrick, well that macro doesn't make anything clear, other than what we already know: tasks in "uninterruptible sleep" count to the load. But that doesn't say that they'd live in the run queue. The original patch in the linked article doesn't seem to change any queue implementation, only which processes are counted in the load.

Comment: @Patrick And then there's the [`proc(5)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) that says of `/proc/loadavg`: "The first three fields in this file are load average figures giving the number of jobs in the run queue (state R) or waiting for disk I/O (state D)....". Note how "job in run queue" and "[job] waiting for I/O" are presented as separate items.